# variable assignment from pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, buffer

I have a buffer, containing the raw information of a struct. I would like to create a function that takes in the buffer, and returns a struct of said type.

```
my_struct func(uin8t_t* buf){
    uin8t_t field1 = *buf;
    uin8t_t[3] = *(buf + 1);
    ...
    return 
}
```

assuming that field1, and field2 are fields within the struct, would field1's value be the first bit of buf, and field2's values be the 2nd, 3rd and 4th bytes of buf?

generalizing the question: does variable assignment simply take the expected number of bits from the value as dictated by the variables type?

Thanks

Comment: I see no `field2` in your code. Does `uin8t_t[3] = *(buf + 1);` mean `uin8t_t field2[3] = *(buf + 1);`? If so, it will lead to compile error ([simplified test](https://ideone.com/QxYzYM)).

Comment: `field1`'s value won't be the first bit of `buf` but will be first **byte** of **where `buf` points**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When performing an assignment, 2 things can happen:

1. Your variables have the same type, case in which sizeof(type) bytes are copied from one memory location to another (this is your case, with size 1).
2. The variables involved in the assignment do not have the same data type, case in which some implicit cast occurs. As a general rule of thumb, you can think that the number of bytes copied is minimum of the 2 variable sizes involved.

Note that if you try to make an assigment to/from a struct variable you have to consider eventual padding between its members.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that field2 is really the second declaration as:

```
uin8t_t field2[3] = *(buf + 1);
```

That line wouldn't copy 3 bytes into the field2 array, and is most likely a syntax error.  Memcpy is probably a better bet.